# CakePHP 3 Serve Files From Plugin Webroot

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.4

I am under the impression that any files placed in the webroot/ folder of a plugin in CakePHP 3 should be served automagically. However, I have not been able to get a file to be served from that folder...

I have created an example project

https://github.com/CakePHPKitchen/CakePHP-Plugin-Webroot-Issue

In the example project, I have baked a plugin named `Elite` and inside the `plugins/Elite/src/webroot` I have placed a text file named `bingo.txt`

To reproduce the issue

- Clone the repository above
- Execute the command `bin/cake server -p 8675`
- Visit http://localhost:8675/bingo.txt
- View Missing Bingo Controller Error

My Question is, how do I retrieve `bingo.txt`?

Do I have to set a setting somewhere to enable that webroot folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the plugin is loaded in your config/bootstrap.php

```
Plugin::load('Elite');
```

Then link to the webroot of the plugin with **localhost:8675/elite/bingo.txt**